# How do I read 64-bit IEEE Standard 754 double-precision numbers from binary data?

Tags: c#, floating-point, ieee-754

I have a stream of data which consists of 64-bit IEEE standard 754 floating point numbers. How would I read these as doubles in using C#? Is there a way to convert a long/ulong into a double?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`BitConverter.Int64BitsToDouble` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.int64bitstodouble(VS.71).aspx) is specifically designed to do this. Alternatively, you can use a `BinaryReader` on top of the stream and take `double` values directly with its `ReadDouble` method.

```
double doubleValue = BitConverter.Int64BitsToDouble(longValue);
```

Comment: Thanks for that :)

And BinaryReader is gonna be very useful too.

Comment: @izb: By the way, be careful about endianness issues that might arise.